What level of personal questions can UK employer ask on job application
I have just gone through a job application with a well known UK employer and the level of personal questions asked shocked me. Can they legally ask these personal questions. I have listed some of the questions below.
Are you a care leaver?
A care leaver is someone who has spent time living in the care system, for example foster care, a children’s home or any other living arrangement outside of immediate or extended family. Please note this doesn’t include work or professional experience within care or social care settings.

Yes
No

I have never seen the following questions being asked before.... just shocking
Did you come to the UK as a refugee or asylum seeker?*

Yes
No
Prefer not to say

Do you have past or present lived experience of homelessness?

Yes
No
Prefer not to say

Ethnic origin
Marital status
Religion or belief
Gender

Female
Male
Non-binary
Other
Prefer not to say

Do you identify yourself as transgender?

Yes
No
Prefer not to say

Sexual orientation

Bisexual man
Bisexual woman
Gay man
Heterosexual man
Heterosexual woman
Lesbian
Other
Prefer not to say.

Again, I have never experienced the following questions being asked:
What was the occupation of your main household earner when you were about aged 14?*
They listed 8 examples categories to choose from... I have list only 2 below.
•   Modern professional & traditional professional occupations such as: teacher, nurse, physiotherapist, social worker, musician, police officer (sergeant or above), software designer, accountant, solicitor, medical practitioner, scientist, engineer.
•   Long-term unemployed (claimed Jobseeker’s Allowance or earlier unemployment benefit for more than a year).
•   Small business owners who employed less than 25 people such as: corner shop owners, small plumbing companies, retail shop owner, single restaurant or cafe owner, taxi owner, garage owner.
Which type of school did you attend for the most time between the ages of 11 and 16?*

A state-run or state-funded school
Independent or fee-paying school
Independent or fee-paying school, where I received a means tested bursary covering 90% or more of the total cost of attending throughout my time there
Attended school outside the UK
I don’t know
Prefer not to say
If you finished school after 1980, were you eligible for free school meals at any point during your school years?*


Are you required to answer these questions? The legitimate reason for asking this is as part of "DEI awareness" and the answers will only ever be used in aggregate and never made available to the interviewers.

This question is actually mostly about legal advice. Voted to close.

Most of the questions listed have a "prefer to not say" option, and I'd assume the rest are also optional just not listed as such in this questions. For UK employers, this is a very standard set of questions, to which the answers are stored anonymously and used specifically for the purpose of DEI analysis of applications received. If you don't want to contribute to their statistics then you simply select "prefer not to say" and stop fussing about it - but note that the (alleged) purpose of such stats collection for employers to be more accessible for applicants from disadvantaged backgrounds

If the questions asked aren't to your liking, why don't you apply somewhere else? These are indeed very invasive questions and chances this is somehow representative to their company culture. Why would you want to work at a place like this? What do you think will happen if you point out the illegality of the questions? "Sir/Mam, thank you so much for pointing out the error of our ways, we shall immediately change our process and extend on off to you".  ????

If you apply for a job as a software engineer in the defense industry, you may face even many more detailed questions about you and your family members (for security reasons) than the ones you have seen.

Following on from Philip's comment: Was there any indication of how the answers could be used?  In particular: would they be available to the interviewers, potential co-workers etc., or restricted?  Would they be connected with your name, or separated and used only in aggregate?  (I think for most of us, aggregate usage, e.g. so the company can measure its diversity and inclusivity, would be reasonable; but any risk of personally-identifiable usage would be very worrying.)

If I am asked a question that has nothing to do with my ability to do my job, then there is a very real possibility of giving an answer that has nothing to do with my life.

A very common excuse when asked "why don't more women/lgbtqia2s/refugees/poor-people/disabled-people work for you?" is to reply that "well, none of those apply here" as though that somehow wasn't the actual job of HR - to get people to apply. Anyway, tracking whether people in those groups apply might reveal that when they do, they don't get hired, and rebut that particular "reason" for the lack of representation.

In an ideal world, these kinds of questions should not be asked directly by the employer, but handled by the third party which aggregates and anonymizes the information. The assumption being they want to understand how they can be an appealing place to work for people of different socioeconomic statuses. They do not need to know this information as part of the assessment process, because none of this information is relevant, unless of course, they wish to discriminate on the basis of the information provided.

Thank you for your response. I was shocked by the level of personal questions; these had nothing to do with whether you can do the job or not. And by know the answers, they could discriminate against the applicant without anyone knowing. Thanks.

Were these questions in a separate section of a printed form which could be detached from the main application questions? Or in a separate "Now we'd like to ask some questions about you" part of an online application? If so, they are almost certainly to be anonymised and aggregated. The last two questions help claims like "50% of our workforce come from disadvantaged backgrounds; we don't only hire grammar-school kids". (The presence of "Prefer not to say" indicates that they are for this social monitoring/DEI purpose.)

@penelope You should probably expand this into an answer. It's indeed to gather statistics (and to show that you don't just employ your private school chums on purpose) and it will be removed (back in the old days, it was on a separate sheet of paper, that didn't have your name on) automatically before the rest of the application is handed to the people actually checking the applicants for the position.

“The legitimate reason for asking this is as part of "DEI awareness" and the answers will only ever be used in aggregate and never made available to the interviewers.” - The world is unfair and cruel, but anyone that believes the answers to those questions will not in some way, influence hiring decisions is delusional. The answers to those questions have nothing to do with the quality of applicant. I personally wouldn’t answer any of those questions, or select every answer, if required to only select one for each answer I wouldn’t even submit the application.

@AndrewLeach The only sane assumption as an individual when you don't fully see the process is to assume a company/organisation doesn't care about protecting your data and will either not anonymize at all or in a shoddy way pseudo-anonymize that is reversible. It's funny, a regular guy asking these questions in an interview would be considered a creep, and formalizing the process is supposed to make it better?

Expanding my comment into an answer. It seems that most of the questions listed by the OP have a "prefer to not say" option, and I'd assume the rest are also optional just not listed as such in this questions.
For UK employers, this is a fairly standard set of questions, to which the answers are stored anonymously and used specifically for the purpose of DEI analysis of applications received. (For example, I haven't myself encountered the set of questions about being a care leaver, being homeless or an asylum seeker in the past; but equally the integration of asylum seekers into society has become a topic of much interest lately. The set of questions you present to us seems to be intended for collecting statistics about applications from applicants from disadvantaged background.)
In fact, the answers to these questions will not reach the members of the interview panel. The information you provide will not be analysed in the context of your specific application but rather analysed as part of wider statistics when (and if) this employer decides to look into their interview process as a whole. E.g. if they notice that they have disproportionately less female applicants, but the female applicants that do apply have a disproportionally higher success rate, the employer might consider steps to encourage more female applicants to apply (e.g. change where they post their adds, how they word their adds, offer additional flexibility, etc).
If you don't want to contribute to their statistics then you should simply select "prefer not to say" and stop fussing about it - but note that the (alleged) purpose of such stats collection for employers to be more accessible for applicants from disadvantaged backgrounds.

"the answers to these questions will not reach the members of the interview panel" - Citation Needed. Sure, at a large corporate, that's probably what's supposed to happen. But I wouldn't want to bet any significant money on it.

Without knowing what the job was (which may or may not make some of the questions more or less relevant) I have to say the questions seem, well, a bit.. much, for most UK interview processes.
That said there's nothing there that they aren't allowed to ask you, which is not the same of course as there being nothing that they aren't allowed to discriminate against you based on your answers, e.g. you say you are a homosexual man and a homophobic interviewer rejects you because you are gay they're in legal trouble.
Which is why a lot of the time certain questions that are technically allowed (such as "are you, or planning to become, pregnant?") don't tend to get asked because if you say "yes" and they don't hire you they might have to end up going to court to prove that the answer wasn't the reason.
I notice there's that nice safe-for-everyone option of "Prefer not to say" on the real landmines to both cover everyone's collective asses and provide a pain-free opt-out to you up front so they don't have to field a dozen angry candidates demanding to know why they need to know your sexual orientation.
With that in mind I would surmise that what they are trying to do is gather applicant info for various diversity metrics (either for employees, applicant pool or both) and as such it's probably relatively harmless. Some of them were weirdly specific though.
Of course if it bothers you sufficiently that you don't want to work there bin the application off and go elsewhere, but personally as someone who is notoriously private about their personal life at work I'd probably just select "prefer not to say" for anything that wouldn't become immediately obvious upon meeting me face-to-face and move on with my life.

In the case of “do you plan to become pregnant” the answer “prefer not to say” will be interpreted as “yes”.
I prefer the German rule: this kind of question, you are allowed to lie, and it cannot be held against you.

@gnasher729 It is such a hot-button question in the UK that it almost never gets asked - and if it does it basically translates in most cases as "we're a nasty company who will discriminate against pregnant women", I don't have a source to hand but I'm fairly sure you're allowed to lie about it here as well.

Thank you for your response in such detail, really appreciated. Why they ask these questions, diversity metrics did cross my mind. But I was shocked about the kind of questions they asked; like ,"What was the occupation of your main household earner when you were about aged 14" .

-1  Sorry but in the UK it is absolutely illegal, under the Equality Act 2010 to ask if a female candidate in a job interview if she is, or is planning to become, pregnant: https://www.irwinmitchell.com/news-and-insights/newsletters/employment-update/feb-18-myth-its-acceptable-to-ask-a-female-candidate-if-shes-pregnant-or-has-children

@DaveGremlin "The Equality Act does not make it unlawful to ask questions about pregnancy, family intentions and childcare, but if you do ask them, and the candidate is then unsuccessful, a tribunal could draw an inference that the reason the candidate didn’t get the job was for one of those reasons." - from the link you posted

@motosubatsu  Yes, I'm getting very confused.  There's quotes by third parties, and I've done courses by the CPID, that have insisted that questions about pregnancy are not allowed under the act, but it's difficult to find out what the exact provisions are.  I've asked a question on Law to get some information from there.   https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/104860/how-does-the-uk-reconcile-collecting-statistics-on-diversity-with-the-restrictio

@DaveGremlin I would be interested to see if the question itself was explicitly illegal, my understanding always matched with what the Irwin Mitchell page stated, that it wasn't but that functionally it may as well be because of it being nigh indefensible at tribunal so only really stupid interviewers would go there. If the OP had been asked that I would be telling them to run screaming!
